# Deploying react to firebase error:"Error: Target container is not a DOM element."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, hosting

When I try to deploy my react app to firebase and then run the app in localhost using npm start i'm getting the following error, Can anyone help?

Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your main div id `<div id="root"></div>` doesn't is the same than `ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>,document.getElementById('root'));`

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have a similar problem. My solution was to replace the hosting-relative links with the CDN ones:

***FROM:***

```
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.18.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

etc...

***TO:***

```
 <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.18.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

etc...